# $httpBackend is not injected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

I have the following problem (with mock tests):

[image]

I get it after angular migration to v 1.6. 
It looks like $httpBackend is not injected.

I don't have any ideas why this provider is not injected.

My injection block:

[image]

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: It isnt a versioning problem is it? inject angular 1.6's version of httpbackend and see if that helps

Comment: Yes! It is versioning problem. It working on angular 1.5 but doesn't work on 1.6. I need v 1.6 :(

Comment: any console errors, while running test cases

Comment: @NagaSaiA nevermind) it's very old question which is not actual for now